# UIImageView blurs image

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, blur

I have a really weird problem with UIImageView. I have an image (an RGB png) 45x45 pixels which I add to the view. I can see that image is blurred after added to the view. Here is the same image in the simulator (left) and in Xcode (right):

[image]
<sub>(source: [partywithvika.com](http://partywithvika.com/iconinsim.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [partywithvika.com](http://partywithvika.com/iconinxcode.png))</sub>

I have custom UIImageView class with this initWithImage code:

```
- (id) initWithImage:(UIImage*) image {
    self = [super initWithImage:image];

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 45);
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    self.quantity = 1;
    if (self) {
        self.label = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,45,25)];
        self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
        self.label.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        self.label.enabled = TRUE;
        self.label.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
        self.label.delegate = self;
        self.label.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        self.label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    // Prepare 3 buttons: count up, count down, and delete
    self.deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
    self.deleteButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.deleteButton.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    self.deleteButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.deleteButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteIcon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.upCountButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.upCountButton.hidden = NO;
    self.upCountButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.upCountButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.upCountButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.downCountButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.downCountButton.hidden = YES;
    self.downCountButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.downCountButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.downCountButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return self;
}
```

I create it like this:

```
UIImage *desertIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"desert.png"];
IconObj *desertIconView = [[IconObj alloc] initWithImage:desertIcon];
desertIconView.center = CGPointMake(265,VERTICAL_POINT_ICON);
desertIconView.type = [IconObj TYPE_DESERT];
[self.view addSubview:desertIconView];
[desertIconView release];
```

Why would the displayed image be so than the one stored in a file?

Comment: This is probably unrelated the the problem, but your init method would be more conventional if, after assigning `self = [super initWithImage:image]`, you check whether self is nil, and if it is, return nil immediately. If self if ever nil, it is either because (1) the parent's initializer could not properly initialize itself, or (2) alloc returned nil because of some strange memory condition (extremely rare). It's good defensive programming practice.

Answer (score 8):

In general, everything you do on iPhone with UIKit should be pixel-aligned.  Problems with pixel alignment usually manifest as blurriness (this is *especially* true with text and images).  This is why when I find blurry view, I first check if I'm setting the `center` property. When you set `center`, the frame's x, y, height and width are adjusted around that center point... frequently resulting in fractional values.

You could try using `CGRectIntegral` on the frame as shown:

```
desertIconView.center = CGPointMake(265,VERTICAL_POINT_ICON);
desertIconView.frame = CGRectIntegral(desertIconView.frame);
```

This may work, but if it doesn't, try setting the `frame` manually, without using `center` property to ensure that no values are fractional.

Edit: Whoops! Didn't notice that the OP had answered his own question... I'll leave this up for informational reasons anyway.

Comment: Most of the other answers (aside from the original poster's) recognise this is a pixel alignment problem, however +1 for this as it's the cleanest and most general purpose. solution

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was driving me nuts. After some investigation it turned out that my image was smaller than the frame, and hence the scaling up blurred it. Once I had put in higher resolution images the problem is gone.

Make sure your image size is greater than your UIImageView frame size.

Answer (score 3):

Your IconObj is 45 pixels wide. You move your IconObj center to 265 which makes its frame to (242.5, VERTICAL_POINT_ICON - 25*0.5, 45, 25). Image will always be blur if some of frame parameter is not integer.

**Solution**, calculate the frame parameter yourself (don't use center). And always make it integer (cast to NSInteger, use ceil, floor, or round).

```
desertIconView.frame = CGRectMake((NSInteger)(265 - 45*0.5),
                                  (NSInteger)(VERTICAL_POINT_ICON - 25*0.5),
                                  45, 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is loading bigger picture into 45x45 UIImageView, of course with

```
contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: I told you to double check image size.

Comment: Nikolai, my image was 45x45 and frame for the UIImageView was also 45x45. Where do you see a potential to misinterpret this setup?

Comment: Did you try to align the pixels of the image to screen pixels?

Comment: Nikolai is correct: your image dimensions are both odd (45), and setting the `center` property to an integer point means that your origin is offset to half a pixel (0.5). This will result in a blurry image every time. When setting the center, you must check each dimension and adjust by 0.5 if that dimension is odd.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. First I thought wtf do I need glasses?

Then I realized it´s just not possible to center an image (or label) when you give it an odd number. You need to resize your image to e.g. 46*46 if you want to center it and stay sharp.

Or you can leave it at 45*45 but then you need to decide whether you want your image to be mal-centered 1 pixel to the right, or 1 pixel to the left. (or leave it blurry).

Answer (score 0):

Try to align your `IconObj` view at screen pixels. If it's really 45x45 then you should set the center to something like CGPointMake(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f).

You should also double check image size in pixels (e.g in Preview.app Command-I).

Comment: Nikolai, I didn't get what you mean by 'x' and 'y' in your comment. The interesting thing is that UIImageView is very sharp if initialized  with bigger picture with the same code.

Comment: With x and y I mean any integer coordinates. While the frame, bounds and center properties of views use CGFloat based types for all coordinates, it's usually a good idea to pixel-align the views to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

complete source for the offset problem:

```
  contentImage  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

  UIImage *cImage = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
  self.contentImage.image = cImage;

  [self.contentImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cImage.size.width, cImage.size.height)];

  CGFloat offset = 0.0f;

  if ( ( (int)cImage.size.width % 2 ) && ( (int)cImage.size.height % 2 ) ) {
    offset = 0.5f;
  }

  [self.contentImage setCenter:CGPointMake(256.0f + offset, 256.0f + offset)];
```